# ifelse based on several conditions and only specific row positions?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, indexing

I am trying to mutate a variable to 0 or 1 based on a set of conditions. However, once the conditions are met, I actually only want the first several rows (let's say 1st row based on small example) instead of mutating all rows. I'm struggling to do index those positions within my `ifelse` statement.

My dataframe looks similar to this:

```
df <-data.frame(individual = c("ind1", "ind1", "ind1", "ind1", "ind1", 
                               "ind1", "ind1", "ind1", "ind1",
                               "ind1", "ind1", "ind1", "ind1", "ind1",
                               "ind1", "ind1", "ind1",
                               "ind2", "ind2", "ind2", "ind2", "ind2", 
                               "ind2", "ind2", "ind2", "ind2",
                               "ind2", "ind2", "ind2", "ind2", "ind2",
                               "ind2", "ind2", "ind2"),
                uniqueclass = c("migrate1", "migrate1", 
                                "stop1", "stop1", "stop1",
                                "migrate2", "migrate2", "migrate2", "migrate2",
                                "stop2", "stop2", 
                                "migrate3", "migrate3", "migrate3",
                                "winter1", "winter1", "winter1",
                                "migrate1", "migrate1", 
                                "stop1", "stop1", "stop1",
                                "migrate2", "migrate2", "migrate2", "migrate2",
                                "stop2", "stop2", 
                                "migrate3", "migrate3", "migrate3",
                                "winter1", "winter1", "winter1"),
                class = c("migrate", "migrate", "stop", "stop", "stop", 
                          "migrate", "migrate", "migrate", "migrate",
                          "stop", "stop", "migrate", "migrate", "migrate",
                          "winter", "winter", "winter",
                          "migrate", "migrate", "stop", "stop", "stop", 
                          "migrate", "migrate", "migrate", "migrate",
                          "stop", "stop", "migrate", "migrate", "migrate",
                          "winter", "winter", "winter"),
                mig_dur = c(10, 10, NA, NA, NA, 
                            2, 2, 2, 2,
                            NA, NA, 4, 4, 4,
                            NA, NA, NA,
                            6, 6, NA, NA, NA, 
                            3, 3, 3, 3,
                            NA, NA, 1, 1, 1,
                            NA, NA, NA)
)
```

What I would like to do is make a new column `response` based on `class == "migrate"` where migrate = 1, else 0, *but* select only the first several (in this example, just the first) rows to make 1s based on the unique events `uniqueclass` variable where only the first migrate rows of each unique events become 1, and everything else becomes 0.

My code looks like this - I'm specifically having trouble with the indexing of positions within the `ifelse` statement:

```
df_new <- df %>% group_by(individual) %>%
  mutate(response = ifelse(!is.na(mig_dur) & uniqueclass[1,], 1, 0)))
```

Again, my desired output is to turn the first row of `uniqueclass == migratex` (i.e., x = 1...n) to a 1 and all others - including other migrate positions-- and all stop and winter classes to 0.

Any advice would be appreciated. Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(response = as.integer(class == "migrate" & row_number() <= 1), .by = c(individual, uniqueclass))
```

Where you can adjust number of rows flagged by changing `row_number <= n`.

Gives:

```
   individual uniqueclass   class mig_dur response
1        ind1    migrate1 migrate      10        1
2        ind1    migrate1 migrate      10        0
3        ind1       stop1    stop      NA        0
4        ind1       stop1    stop      NA        0
5        ind1       stop1    stop      NA        0
6        ind1    migrate2 migrate       2        1
7        ind1    migrate2 migrate       2        0
8        ind1    migrate2 migrate       2        0
9        ind1    migrate2 migrate       2        0
10       ind1       stop2    stop      NA        0
11       ind1       stop2    stop      NA        0
12       ind1    migrate3 migrate       4        1
13       ind1    migrate3 migrate       4        0
14       ind1    migrate3 migrate       4        0
15       ind1     winter1  winter      NA        0
16       ind1     winter1  winter      NA        0
17       ind1     winter1  winter      NA        0
18       ind2    migrate1 migrate       6        1
19       ind2    migrate1 migrate       6        0
20       ind2       stop1    stop      NA        0
21       ind2       stop1    stop      NA        0
22       ind2       stop1    stop      NA        0
23       ind2    migrate2 migrate       3        1
24       ind2    migrate2 migrate       3        0
25       ind2    migrate2 migrate       3        0
26       ind2    migrate2 migrate       3        0
27       ind2       stop2    stop      NA        0
28       ind2       stop2    stop      NA        0
29       ind2    migrate3 migrate       1        1
30       ind2    migrate3 migrate       1        0
31       ind2    migrate3 migrate       1        0
32       ind2     winter1  winter      NA        0
33       ind2     winter1  winter      NA        0
34       ind2     winter1  winter      NA        0
```

Comment: Haven't tried this solution yet, but it looks to be exactly what I wanted to do. I'll comment back if something goes awry on the larger dataset but I think this is an excellent solution. Thanks you!

Comment: Spoke to soon. This returns on error message `.by must be size 64 or 1, not 128`... `The error occurred in group 1: ID = "bbr-b172021-M".` Any suggestions as to why it worked on my toy example but not the larger dataset? Note, the larger dataset has 66 individuals and ~5000 obs. There are uneven unique classes for each individual (unlike my toy example which has the same unique classes per indiv).

Comment: Please share the code that triggered the error.  But it reads like it is treating `.by` not as an argument but as a new variable name in which case you may need to update `dplyr`.